# TypeScript で連想配列の中身の型を引っ張り出して使いたい（Union型）

Tags: typescript

連想配列の内部の階層の型を引っ張ってくる方法を教えていただきたいです。

```
type Outside = number | {
  key: {
    a: number;
    b: string;
  }
};

// Outside型のkeyからInside型を作りたい （おそらくOutside型はnumberの可能性もあるせいで、下記が通らない）
// type Inside = Outside['key'] // プロパティ 'key' は型 'Outside' に存在しません。ts(2339)

// 欲しい型をベタにかくとこうなります！
type Inside = {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

const v: Inside = getOutsideValue().key;
```

Comment: `Inside` 型として欲しい型をベタに書いてみてくださいませんか。賢いことをせずに地道に手で型を定義した場合はどのようになりますか？　`type Inside = { a: number, b: string };` みたいなことですかね……？　どういうものを欲してらっしゃるのかがうまく分かりませんでした。質問を [edit] して追記してみてください。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 質問の意図あっています！質問内容も編集しましたが、そのInside型が欲しいのです！

Comment: その場合、`Outside` 型の値に対して `key` property を見に行くことは型エラーになってしまいます。`number` 型だった場合にそのような property が存在しないためです。 したがって `Inside` 型が定義できても `const v: Inside = getOutsideValue().key;` は型チェックに通りません。なぜこのようなことがしたいのかより具体的なところを質問に追記してくださると、もうちょっと違うアドバイスができるかもしれません。